# Find name of machine on which I've connected via ssh

Tags: unix

I've ssh'd into one of my school's computer clusters. I'd like to know the name of the machine on which I'm running, e.g. myth14.

Comment: `uname -a` or `uname -n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hostname` command will do this.